# calling assembly function from c with reference parameter

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm implementing an assembly function to reverse a string.  This function is being called in C with the signature `void strrev(char *str) ;`  Everything seems to be working fine within the function, debugging with gdb, but printing the contents of the string after calling `strrev()`  just prints empty strings.

```
getlast:
        cmp     byte [edi], 0
        je      reverse_string
        inc     edi
        inc     ecx
        jmp     getlast

reverse_string:
        cmp     esi, edi
        jae     reversed
        mov     al, [esi]
        mov     bl, [edi]
        mov     [esi], bl
        mov     [edi], al
        inc     esi
        dec     edi

        jmp     reverse_string
```

main.c

```
void strrev(char *str) ;

int main() {
   char *str1;

   str1 = strdup("Hello World") ;
   strrev(str1) ;
   printf("str1 = \"%s\"\n", str1) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
    cmp     byte [edi], 0
    je      reverse_string
```

will cause this

```
    mov     bl, [edi]
    mov     [esi], bl
```

to write 0 at the beginning of the string.

You need to step back from the string terminator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly fluent in assembly language, but to me

```
    cmp     byte [edi], 0
    je      reverse_string
```

looks like you include the 0-terminator in the reversal, so that your reversed "strings" all start with a 0 byte.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're including the `'\0'` in the reversal, i.e. you move it to the front.

I'm not that hot with x86 assembly but it seems `edi` points at the terminator when you enter `reverse_string`, and thus is included in the first swap.